# Getting incorrect value from moment-timezone when converting Date to Epoch seconds

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a use case where a user selects a Date and Time in the future in their time zone. In this case, US Central Time. I would like to convert the Date given their timezone into Epoch seconds, which I need to pass to a 3rd party API.

Here's part of my unit test code so far:

```
moment.tz.add('America/Chicago');

// This value is returned by Mongoose as a Date, which is why I'm using Date() here
const publishAt = new Date('2017-07-26T12:00:00.000Z');

const publishAtEpoch = moment.tz(publishAt, 'America/Chicago').valueOf() / 1000;
```

Which results in:

```
1501070400
```

instead of:

```
1501088400
```

which is incorrect according to: https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1501070400&tz=America%2FChicago

The value 1501070400 is 5 hours too early.

If I pass in a naive string for the Date: `2017-07-26 12:00:00` it works as expected.

If I use a naive Date: `new Date('2017-07-26 12:00:00');` the value is 1 hour too early, as my timezone is US Eastern.

What am I doing wrong? I thought moment-timezone was supposed to handle the offset, account for Daylight Savings Time, etc.

Comment: Off the top of my head, keep in mind the context of setting a new date for your publishAt var. This will be created in the context of the data of the system running your app, meaning it will be converted to that tz.

Comment: Sounds like I probably just need to break the date down into its constituent parts and then pass it to moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `publishAt` Date is created using an string that ends with `Z`, so it represents time in UTC. As you can see `publishAt` ([`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)) value in milliseconds since the Unix Epoch is `1501070400000`.

`1501070400000` is `26 July 2017 12:00:00 UTC` (see records with `0` *Offset
In seconds* in the table in your link).

In my opinion, the problem is that you are expecting to get `1501088400000` instead of `1501070400000` that is the "real" value of `new Date('2017-07-26T12:00:00.000Z')`.

`moment.tz('2017-07-26 12:00:00', 'America/Chicago')` gives `1501088400000` because you are telling to moment to parse your string as time in Chicago, while `new Date('2017-07-26 12:00:00')` creates date for your local timezone.

Please note that moment-timezone [docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) states:

> Unix timestamps and `Date` objects refer to specific points in time, thus it doesn't make sense to use the time zone offset when constructing. Using `moment.tz(Number|Date, zone)` is functionally equivalent to `moment(Number|Date).tz(zone)`.

Here a snippet showing the described results:

```js
const publishAt = new Date('2017-07-26T12:00:00.000Z');
console.log(publishAt.getTime()); // 1501070400000

const publishAtEpoch = moment.tz(publishAt, 'America/Chicago').valueOf() / 1000;
console.log(publishAtEpoch); // 1501070400

const timeChicago = moment.tz('2017-07-26T12:00:00.000', 'America/Chicago');
console.log(timeChicago.valueOf() / 1000); // 1501088400
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Here a snippet that parses milliseconds (both `1501070400000` and `1501088400000`), then it shows the value in local time, UTC and Chicago timezone. This is something similar to what epochconverter.com does and maybe could help you understand why the site is showing these results.

```js
const m1Local = moment(1501070400000);
console.log(m1Local.format()); // 1501070400000 local time
const m1Utc = moment(1501070400000).utc();
console.log(m1Utc.format()); // 2017-07-26T12:00:00Z
const m1Chicago = moment(1501070400000).tz('America/Chicago');
console.log(m1Chicago.format()); // 2017-07-26T07:00:00-05:00

const m2Local = moment(1501088400000);
console.log(m2Local.format()); // 1501088400000 local time
const m2Utc = moment(1501088400000).utc();
console.log(m2Utc.format()); // 2017-07-26T17:00:00Z
const m2Chicago = moment(1501088400000).tz('America/Chicago');
console.log(m2Chicago.format()); // 2017-07-26T12:00:00-05:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

As additional info, note that moment has [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) method that:

> `moment#unix` outputs a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch).
>
> This value is floored to the nearest second, and does not include a milliseconds component.

if you want to avoid to divide by `1000` the value returned by [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/).

Further readings that could be useful: [Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) guide, timezone tag [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Thank you for the `.unix()` tip, and I now understand why moment was skipping the offset. Yes, I was expecting to get the date given the user's timezone. By converting the time to a naive time string, then passing in the offset, I was able to get what I wanted, then let moment handle daylight savings time.

Comment: After re-reading your answer, 1501074000 should be correct, not 1501088400. I guess I'm not understanding how https://www.epochconverter.com is displaying their results.

Comment: I've edited my answer adding and example that parses milliseconds and show results in localtime, UTC and Chicago timezone, maybe it could help you understand better what epochconverter does.